# xsd-schema-validator fails to validate samlify xml

Tags: java, node.js, xml, single-sign-on, saml

I'm trying to use samlify (node js library) to perform sso authentication. I have both the idp and sp xml files. In my node.js code, upon calling the function

`sp.parseLoginResponse(idp, 'post', req)
    .then((parseResult) => {});`

samlify spins up a child process using xsd-schema-validator to validate the xml of the schema.

This validation command is failing and I have no idea why. Here is the command in full and the response

```html
[root@kartik-centos-test server]# java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /root/angular_project/Hub-MAC-Dashboard/server/node_modules/xsd-schema-validator:/root/angular_project/Hub-MAC-Dashboard/server/node_modules/samlify/build/schemas support.XMLValidator -stdin -schema=/root/angular_project/Hub-MAC-Dashboard/server/node_modules/samlify/build/schemas/saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd 

[fatal] src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'ds:Signature' to a(n) 'element declaration' component.
result=FATAL_ERROR
```

It is failing to validate the schema file which is provided by samlify. My suspicion is that this is because the java program cannot complete http requests because it's behind a corporate proxy. Could this be the reason?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The issue, oddly, was because the virtual box I was testing in used a proxy to connect to the internet. Somewhere down in the xsd library's code, there is a java class that is used to validate the xml and it makes an http call. I had to go into the xsd library's javascript code and change the java command that is spawned to use an https proxy so that the command succeeded.

You'd think the java library would just give you an http error ... but guess not. Always check if you're connected to the internet folks.

Comment: Hello, I am the creator of samlify. I am thinking to folk the library and use your approach to get rids of this proxy related issue, would you like to submit a PR to https://github.com/passify/node-xsd-schema-validator ?